# Linux Kernel and the init process

Tags: linux, boot

How does the linux kernel know the location of the /sbin/init program during the boot process?  Is "/sbin/init" hard coded into the linux kernel source code?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `/sbin/init` is hardcoded into the source. See the function `init_post` `init/main.c`:

```
    if (execute_command) {
            run_init_process(execute_command);
            printk(KERN_WARNING "Failed to execute %s.  Attempting "
                                    "defaults...\n", execute_command);
    }
    run_init_process("/sbin/init");
    run_init_process("/etc/init");
    run_init_process("/bin/init");
    run_init_process("/bin/sh");

    panic("No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
          "See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.");
```

Answer (score 3):

The program to run when kernel loading has completed can be given on the kernel boot command line using the `init=/file/name` argument.

If this option is not passed, the built-in default `/sbin/init` is used.